# MySQL to PostgreSQL replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, mysql-replication

Is there way to replicate in near-realtime MySQL changes to equal PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres 9.1 supports so-called "foreign data wrappers" which allow you to interact with third-party products, e.g. MySQL, Oracle or even non-relational stuff like text files and Reddis. Check it out:

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers
- http://pgxn.org/dist/mysql_fdw/

Comment: that (in theory) can be useful to PG=>MY replication using triggers, but not back :(

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there are opensource tools, but GoldenGate which was acquired by Oracle claims to replicate between any major databases. Now that MySQL is also Oracle I won't be surprised that this is supported, but you should contact them if you are interested. I personally have not used this product but have a friend who used to work in the heterogenous database replicatio there. So this is just a pointer for you.

Answer (score -2):

exist pgslony replication tool but I am not sure that can help you, for very easy used is possible write job in postgres, you can try your favorite language, for example python or perl